# How to concat html object to html string using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created a loop and below is the part of the code between that loop

```
--- Loop Starts ---

var aElement = $('<a>');
aElement.attr('href', '#');
aElement.text(title);

aElement.click(function() {
    alert("Hello World);
});

video_list_html += '<tr>' +
                        '<th scope="row">' + count + '</th>' +
                        '<td>' + aElement + '</td>' +
                    '</tr>';
--- Loop Starts ---
```

But as aElement is an object, it doesn't attach as html tag to the **video_list_html** but it attaches like this

```
[object Object]
```

How do I fix this, so that it attaches inside the **video_list_html** and also the .click() event stay working.

Comment: You cannot concat `aElement` as string without loosing event listeners. If you don't want to use the event listener, you have to append `aElement` using `appendChild`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because you cannot append an object to a string. The object gets coerced, ans the result is, as you've seen, `[Object object]`.

A better solution to this problem would be to append the new HTML as one entire string, then use a delegated event handler to catch the events from those dynamically added elements. Try this:

```js
var data = [{
  videoId: 'abc123',
  title: 'Video #1'
}, {
  videoId: 'xyz987',
  title: 'Video #2'
}]

var video_list_html = data.map(function(o, i) {
  return '<tr><th scope="row">' + i + '</th><td><a href="#" data-videoid="' + o.videoId + '">' + o.title + '</a></td></tr>';
}).join('');

$('#yourTable').append(video_list_html).on('click', 'a', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log($(this).data('videoid'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="yourTable"></table>
```

Comment: The thing is where I have done alert(), I have actually called my own function with and ID as argument that I got in the loop.

Like this
displayVideoAnalytics(videoId);

to be straight, I am working on youtube analytics api and this was one of the code from it which I modified for my needs

Comment: Don't do that. Put the `videoId` in a `data-*` attribute on the element which you can retrieve within the single delegated click event handler. I updated the question to show you how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Try using aElement[0].outerHTML instead of aElement. Leave click handler as is.

Comment: Who should this keep the event listener? `aElement.outerHTML` would result in a string with out any informations about event listeners that have been attached.

Comment: True, it appends the html tag fine but the click event doesn't work. Just tried to confirm

Comment: The new element will need another handler if that's what he wants, of course, the first handler for the original element remains untouched. I understood that's the idea

Comment: The old element and the new element created using HTML string are two different elements, naturally that another element needs another handler, I meant to say that first handler will still work for the first element.